# AppCenter and sudo apt update with "failed to fetch update"

Tags: updates, appcenter

The AppCenter is not updating. When I try to update on the AppCenter, I get:

`W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-pt) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/libs/ubuntu lucid InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/libs/ubuntu lucid InRelease is not (yet) available (Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?))
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu lucid InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu lucid InRelease is not (yet) available (Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?))
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathandyer/vocal-daily/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid/main amd64 Packages is not (yet) available (Hash Sum mismatch)
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid/main i386 Packages is not (yet) available ()
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathandyer/vocal-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages is not (yet) available (403  Forbidden)`

And with sudo apt update, I get:

`Hit:1 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease

Get:3 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease

Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease

Hit:6 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter xenial InRelease

Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release

Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]

Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:11 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease

Ign:12 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ InRelease

Hit:13 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease

Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freetuxtv/freetuxtv-dev/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:15 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease

Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/ubuntus/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/gcc5/ubuntu wily InRelease

Get:18 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ Release [988 B]

Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/gcc5/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/gcc5-deps/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/libs/ubuntu lucid InRelease
0% [22 InRelease gpgv 101 kB] [Waiting for headers]Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_kxstudio-debian_libs_ubuntu_dists_lucid_InRelease intErr:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/libs/ubuntu lucid InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid InRelease
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/plugins/ubuntu lucid InRelease
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/apps/ubuntu lucid InRelease 
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu lucid InRelease
0% [26 InRelease gpgv 101 kB] [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_kxstudio-debian_kxstudio_ubuErr:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu lucid InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/libs/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/plugins/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/apps/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mathieu.leplatre/subtivals/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/menulibre-dev/daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mixxx/mixxx/ubuntu xenial InRelease

Ign:35 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathandyer/vocal-daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu xenial InRelease

Ign:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid/main amd64 Packages
Ign:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid/main i386 Packages
Ign:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid/main Translation-en
Err:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathandyer/vocal-daily/ubuntu xenial Release
  403  Forbidden
Ign:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid/main amd64 Packages
Ign:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid/main i386 Packages
Ign:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid/main Translation-en
Get:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid/main amd64 Packages [64,6 kB]
Err:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid/main amd64 Packages
  Hash Sum mismatch
Ign:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done

W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-pt) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/libs/ubuntu lucid InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu lucid InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathandyer/vocal-daily/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-pt) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list:1`

Can anyone help me here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me that the PPAs `kxstudio-debian` and `nathandyer/vocal-daily` are causing issues here. You might want to remove them.

To do so,

1. Go to **Applications**
2. Right click on **Files** and select **New Window as Administrator**.
3. Then navigate to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.
4. In this directory, delete anything that says `kxstudio` or `nathandyer`.
5. Then try running an update; it should work.

Obviously, this means that you will no longer receive updates for KXStudio and Vocal.

For KXStudio, you can try to add the PPA from scratch later. For Vocal, unless you are a tester, you can just [purchase it from AppCenter](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.needle-and-thread.vocal.desktop).

Comment: I don't know what KXStudio is but I'm guessing it was installed with Mixxx. And I did purchase Vocal (I think it was my first purchase in the App Store) but I already had the previous package, before there was a store. Maybe the repositaries got broken. It's working, perfectly, after reinstalling both KXStudio and Vocal. You're the best, thank you for your help.

Comment: I have the same problem. But another app. Did what you sad and deleted all the files that app center sad in error log.. Now it works.